# How to convert Wordpress categories to a custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I need to convert all my categories to a custom posts. Any solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried to accomplish this? Where is your code? Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to have tried something and then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code -

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'post_type' => "Custom_POST_Type",
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy' => 'Custom_Taxonomy'
) );

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    print_r($category->name);

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( $category->name.'s', 'Post type general name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( $category->name, 'Post type singular name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( $category->name.'s', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x( $category->name, 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New '.$category->name, 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New '.$category->name.'s', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit '.$category->name, 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View '.$category->name, 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All '.$category->name.'s', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search '.$category->name.'s', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent '.$category->name.'s'.':', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No '.$category->name.'s'.' found.', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No '.$category->name.'s'.' found in Trash.', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image'        => _x( $category->name.'s'.' Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'archives'              => _x( $category->name.' archives', 'The post type archive label used in nav menus. Default “Post Archives”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => _x( 'Insert into '.$category->name, 'Overrides the “Insert into post”/”Insert into page” phrase (used when inserting media into a post). Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => _x( 'Uploaded to this '.$category->name, 'Overrides the “Uploaded to this post”/”Uploaded to this page” phrase (used when viewing media attached to a post). Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => _x( 'Filter '.$category->name.'s'.' list', 'Screen reader text for the filter links heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Filter posts list”/”Filter pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => _x( $category->name.' list navigation', 'Screen reader text for the pagination heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list navigation”/”Pages list navigation”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list'            => _x( $category->name.'s list', 'Screen reader text for the items list heading on the post type listing screen. Default “Posts list”/”Pages list”. Added in 4.4', 'textdomain' ),
    );

    
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( $category->name, 'domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'description', 'domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats' ),
        //'taxonomies'            => array( 'catservice'),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => false,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( $category->slug, $args );
}
```